# can truncate multiple tables Using Cursor in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor, truncate

I try this but didn't work

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_TruncateDTS] as
begin

 declare @Table Varchar(200)

    declare cur1 cursor for
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME like '%DTS%'  and  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

    open cur1
    fetch next from cur1 into @Table

    while @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1
    begin



            TRUNCATE TABLE @Table


        fetch next from cur1 into @Table
    end

    close cur1
    deallocate cur1

end
```

Comment: dbms name please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass identifiers (such as table names, column names, and so forth) as parameters in queries.  Instead, you need to use dynamic SQL.

So replace the inner loop with:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE [Table]';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[Table]', @table);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: There is no reason for replacing table. You can just add the variable name to your string instead

Answer (score 0):

The example below uses the `sys.tables` catalog view and aggregate string concatenation instead of a cursor for the task.

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = (
    SELECT N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name) +N';'
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE  name like N'%DTS%'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

In SQL Serveer 2017 and later, you can use `STRING_AGG`:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG ('TRUNCATE TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name),';')
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE  name like N'%DTS%'
    );
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Note that this schema-qualifies names and uses `QUOTENAME` to handle cases where the name doesn't conform to regular identifier naming rules.